# Where is X-chat when it is minimized to tray?

Tags: 12.04, unity, xchat

When I click at X-chat's option *Minimize to tray*, where is it going? I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

There is a useful indicator that you should install with xchat called `xchat-indicator` - as you can see, when xchat is minimized you can find it in the messaging indicator

#### [xchat-indicator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xchat-indicator) [image: Install xchat-indicator]

Comment: I've tried it, but it is not as vesatile as its icon was. Where is it? In the settings it is, but not works...

Comment: @B.Roland if you are using Unity you cannot get it as the system tray has been removed from the top panel. You can get the system tray icon if you use a DE like Cinnamon or MATE (also Xfce IIRC, not sure).

Comment: it still quits from the server after minimizing to tray in 12.10.